# Resque find position of job in a queue

Tags: resque

We want to use resque to queue a bunch of jobs, and process them by workers. While the jobs are waiting to be processed, we want to know what is their position in the queue (as an indicator of how long they would have to wait). How do we find the position of a job in a queue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your problem is in using resque queue system ( you have not mentioned an technology stack that you are using ) .

You can use [resque-status](https://github.com/quirkey/resque-status)  an extension to the resque queue system that provides simple trackable jobs.

resque-status provides a set of simple classes that extend resque’s default functionality (with 0% monkey patching) to give apps a way to track specific job instances and their status. It achieves this by giving job instances UUID’s and allowing the job instances to report their status from within their iterations.